# How to access a value inside the loop for my program

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String a, b;
            int x, y, sum;
            string line1, line2;


                Console.WriteLine("enter the file name with location :");
                a = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("enter the second file name with location :");
                b = Console.ReadLine();
              using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(a))
                {

                    while ((line1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Value in the first file is :"+line1);

                    }
                }
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(b))
                {

                    while ((line2 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Value in the second file is :" + line2);


                    }
                }
                x = Convert.ToInt32(line1);
                y = Convert.ToInt32(line2);
                Console.WriteLine("values are :" + line1, line2);
                Console.WriteLine("values are :" + x, y);
                sum = x + y;
                Console.WriteLine("The sum of values in both the file is :" + sum);



            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I cant take the values from the while loop so that i can convert them to int and do an addition. What should i do?

Comment: `line1` and `line2` will be null because they are assigned null when ReadLine() finishes reading the file. If you want to process all of the lines, you can use something like `var linesFile1 = File.ReadAllLines(a);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
x = x + Convert.ToInt32(line1);
```

in 1st while loop

```
y = y + Convert.ToInt32(line2);
```

in 2nd while loop

and remove

```
  x = Convert.ToInt32(line1);
  y = Convert.ToInt32(line2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put together the reading and calculation of read values in a single while loop. If both have same number of lines then loop will terminate after calculating all the sums. Otherwise you will have to stop reading the smaller file you you get the null and could use zero in calculation.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(a))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(b))
{
   while ((line1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null && (line2 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Value in the first file is :"+ line1 ?? "null");
       Console.WriteLine("Value in the second file is :" + line2 ?? "null");
       x = Convert.ToInt32(line1==null ? "0" : line1);
       y = Convert.ToInt32(line2==null ? "0" : line2);
       Console.WriteLine("values are :" + line1, line2);
       Console.WriteLine("values are :" + x, y);
       sum = x + y;
       Console.WriteLine("The sum of values in both the file is :" + sum);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with `line1` and `line2` inside their loops, they doesn't exist outside of loop and your code will not even compile. You need to refactor to something like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(a))
{

    while ((line1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value in the first file is :"+line1);
          x = Convert.ToInt32(line1);
          sum += x;
    }
}
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(b))
{

    while ((line2 = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value in the second file is :" + line2);
        y = Convert.ToInt32(line2);
        sum += y;
    }
}
```

FYI: `Convert.ToInt32(string)` function will throw `FormatException` if there is no number in string. In this cases you need to write this code in `try...catch` block.

Comment: Thank You. Your solution helped